# How to put timeout to NSTimer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a NSTimer object  as below :

```
 var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I want to put timeout to my timer. Maybe you know postdelayed method in android. I want to same thing's swift version. How can I do this ?

Comment: what should the timeout do? for those of use who don't know postdelayed. After x time the timer should stop?

Comment: isn't that the definition of a timer?

Comment: I want to delay timer 3 second . then It  can work again

Comment: @Russell `NSTimer` fires a function after x time and may or may not repeat. A timeout to me sounds like a way to stop it after y time. (this is vauge I know)

Comment: So you want to delay a delay? Because in essence an `NSTimer` is a delay

Comment: maybe we should all wait for @yusufonder to actually explain what the question is :-)

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I can't tell my problem :) Maybe I should study english :) Anyway . My goal is this :  when timer is working. I want to cancel my timer . Then timer should re-work 10 second later. But this event should be automatically .

Comment: So timer should not work spesific time . Then it should  work again

Comment: So you want to delay a certain function for a different amount of time each time it happens? Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/4263818). It is more useful for what you want to achieve

Comment: yes exacly. I am looking this question then I will return to you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSTimer` is not suited for variable interval times. You set it up with one specified delay time and you can't change that. A more elegant solution than stopping and starting an `NSTimer` every time is to use `dispatch_after`.

Borrowing from [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/4263818) :

```
// this makes a playground work with GCD
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

struct DispatchUtils {

    static func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
}


class Alpha {

    // some delay time
    var currentDelay : NSTimeInterval = 2

    // a delayed function
    func delayThis() {

        // use this instead of NSTimer
        DispatchUtils.delay(currentDelay) {
            print(NSDate())
            // do stuffs

            // change delay for the next pass
            self.currentDelay += 1

            // call function again
            self.delayThis()
        }
    }
}

let a = Alpha()

a.delayThis()
```

Try it in a playground.
It will apply a different delay to each pass of the function.

Comment: this is very helpful response for me. thanks for interest